# Ubuntu VNC server and Putty SSH tunnel

Tags: 14.04, ssh, vnc, putty, vncviewer

I have my vncserver running on my ubuntu machine and I am able to connect directly to it from pcs both on and off my network.  To have a graphical desktop connection I use a vnc client (VNC viewer in this case) and provide my server ip address and port 5901. Is that not supposed to be possible?  Is my config wrong?  I ask because I see a lot of setups mentioning connecting through an SSH tunnel.  I wasn't able to get the SSH tunnel method to work.

I also have SSH running on my server and I'm able to connect to using putty through my SSH port and use the command line.

Comment: "`Is that not supposed to be possible?`": please, what is this referring to?

Comment: I am referring to "connect directly to vncserver both on and off the network without going through an ssh tunnel".